# Access to entity manager in config.php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

In app/config/config.php we can:

```
$container->loadFromExtension('doctrine', array(
    'dbal' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host'     => '%database_host%',
        'dbname'   => '%database_name%',
        'user'     => '%database_user%',
        'password' => '%database_password%',
    ),
));
```

But is possible to get Entity Manager in this file?

```
$container->getDoctrine()
```

return:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder".

```
$container->get('doctrine')
```

return:

> You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine"

```
$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
```

return:

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   "doctrine.orm.entity_manager"

Comment: Can you explain in detail what are you trying to achieve? The database parameters are normally set in the parameters.yml and automatically inserted in the config-files with those variables %database_host%. Even if you would be able to inject the doctrine-service into the config.php there would be a paradoxon. You can't access the database which is still not initialised, which is done by the exactly that file.

Comment: Doctrine is only example. I would like modify parameters etc.

Comment: Why do you want to modify parameters? Why not put the parameters in the file directly, where they belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible. You can't access the services in the building step.
You can use a `CompilerPass` to access services and call methods or aliases.

Or if you just want to pass the `EntityManager` to an service, use the `Reference` class.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use CompilerPass for this?

Comment: This depends what you try to achieve. Have you looked at the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)?